# If $A=\{n\mid n=63k\}$ and $B=\{n\mid n=8k-1\}$ find $ A \cap B$ without Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $$A=\{x\mid x\text{ is the sum of 7 consecutive integers}\}$$
>   $$B=\{x\mid x\text{ is the sum of 8 consecutive integers}\}$$
>   $$C=\{x\mid x\text{ is the sum of 9 consecutive integers}\}$$
>   What is $A\cap B\cap C$?

**My working:**
I have taken general consecutive terms $\ n-3,\ n-2,\ n-1,\ n,\ n+1,\ n+2,\ n+3$ which gives me:
$$A=\{x\mid x=7n\}$$
Similarly I obtain
$$B=\{x\mid x=8n-4\}$$
$$C=\{x\mid x=9n\}$$
Then $A\cap B\cap C=\{x\mid x=63m,x=8n-4\}$. But I am not able to figure out a general solution for $x$ although I have thought about it a lot. It would be great if someone could give me hint as to how to do it… I just need the logic or the approach.

*Note*: I have not studied modular arithmetic, hence I need a more elementary method of solving this question that avoids the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie Not really...will google it

Comment: If you tried to solve this without the CRT you would still be going along the same lines of thought as the CRT (this is a solution, and any solution plus some number is a solution, so...)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I dont really mind going along the same lines as the CRT, its just that I don't understand the theorem as I haven't studied modular arithmetic...If there is a simpler way of stating CRT without using modular arithmetic I would welcome that too

Comment: $x\in B\iff $ $\exists n \; [ x=\sum_{j=-3}^{j=4}(n+j) \;] \iff $ $\exists n\;(x=8n+4). $  Not  $x=8n-1.$

Comment: @user254665 my bad...made the edit

Comment: Look up: Euclid's Algorithm and Bezout's Identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method by sieving (i.e. write down the two sequence and finding the common numbers) of course works here, but the calculation is a bit cumbersome. There is just a neat way to solve this without using the Chinese Remainder Theorem. First note that $x\in A\cup B$ is equivalent to $7|x,9|x,8|x+1.$ Let $x=63k,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $8|63k+1,$ thus $8|k-1$, which is equivalent to $k=8l+1$ for some $l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $x=504l+63,\ l\in\mathbb{Z}$ are the only solutions (as you can easily verify).

What we have done just now is actually solving a system of linear diophantine equations:
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x&=63y\\
x&=8z-1
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

We canceled $x$ and found the relation between $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Thanks! I could find the relation between y and z but stupidly didn't put its value back in x so I thought I was going nowhere...

Comment: The original question has changed to $8|x+4$ but that can be done in pretty much the same way. BTW, modular arithmetic is useful and easy to understand. Here the diophantine equation $x=ay+b$ is just the congruence equation $x\equiv b\pmod a$ and using the Chinese remainder theorem is the most natural.

Comment: I will surely try out modular arithmetic sometime, as even I have come across a lot of questions that can be solved using it...and the change in question is not a problem...thanks!